# UI5 Tiles to top of page

Tags: sapui5

I'm new to UI5 and try to display some Tiles on a page. 
However, they appear in the center of the screen, and I would like to have it at the top. 
Below it is a graph that now doesnt even appear on the page without scrolling. 
How do get it to the top of the page and remove the bottom margins ?

[image: ui5]

View:

> ```
>     <TileContainer
>           id="container"
>           tiles="{deviceData>/d/results}">
>
>           <StandardTile
>             number="BBB"
>             numberUnit="CCC"
>             title="ZZZ"
>             info="XXX"
>             infoState="CCC" />
>         </TileContainer>
>
>         <l:C3Chart id="chart1" class="c3Chart" height="300px" width="100%" columns="{cols}" type="{timeseries}"   />
> </Page> </mvc:View>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of your tile container to 50% ( or whatever suits your requirements). 
code:

```
<TileContainer tiles='{/}' height='50%'>
                <tiles>
                    <StandardTile title='{title}'>
                    </StandardTile>
                </tiles>
</TileContainer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You likely dont need a TileContainer here (tile container is full screen component to use when you have an unknown -but important- number of tiles).

You should use a simpler container like an HBox here

```
  <HBox
      id="container"
      items="{deviceData>/d/results}">

      <StandardTile
        number="BBB"
        numberUnit="CCC"
        title="ZZZ"
        info="XXX"
        infoState="CCC" />
    </HBox>
```